# XPath - Unable to access XPath with other locale characters

Tags: ios, selenium, xpath, appium

I am trying to access a XPath which contains other language characters in iOS, for example:

`//UIAStaticText[@name='España']` or `//UIAStaticText[@label='España']`

But this XPath is not getting created and returning a nilClass error.

Is other language characters are supported in XPath?

Comment: This is going to be very dependent on the XPath library you're using.

Comment: I am using XPath 3.0

Comment: XPath 3.0? Really? That would be unusual because Selenium does not even support XPath 2.0. Please show the [input document, and all the relevant code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: XPath as a language certainly allows such characters. If your implementation doesn't, then either you're doing something wrong in the way you are invoking it, or the implementation is non-conformant.

Comment: Wow. I'm loosing all day fighting with such problem without the idea XPath sucks that way. Thanks for the clearance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an XPath issue, it is unable to create a selenium web driver element which has `special characters/other language special character`.

Answer (score 0):

Use contains and pass few characters, so it will search for element with attribute name containing "Esp":
`//UIAStaticText[contains(@name,'Esp')]`

Comment: Thanks, But what about other characters? I can not define one element for every country name textfield.

Comment: In this case use attributes such as resource-id, index, content-desc.